# Python function that takes two values

Tags: python, function, if-statement

This function take two integers x is the hour and y is the minute. The function should print the time in the text to the nearest hour.
This is the code I have written.

```
def approxTime(x, y):
    if int(y) <= 24:
        print("the time is about quarter past" + int(y))
    elif 25 >= int(y) <=40:
        print("the time is about half past" + int(y))
    elif 41 >= int(y) <= 54:
        print("the time is about quarter past" + int(y+1))
    else:
        print("the time is about" + int(y+1) +"o'clock")
approxTime(3, 18)
```

However I am getting this error message.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):   File
  "C:/Users/Jafar/Documents/approxTime.py", line 14, in <module>
      approxTime(3, 18)   File "C:/Users/Jafar/Documents/approxTime.py", line 5, in approxTime
      print("the time is about quarter past" + int(y)) TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

Comment: Don't call `int(y+1)` call `str(int(y)+1)` or better again use `str.format`

Comment: BTW, it should be `x`, not `y` in the `print` statements - please change the variable names to `hours` and `minutes` or the like to make things a bit more obvious.

Comment: Next time, try Googling the error message.

Comment: The error message seems crystal clear to me.  Why the confusion?  You're trying to concatenate a `str` and an `int` with the `+` operator.  It's telling you you can't do that.  You need to convert the `int` to a `str`.  You're trying to do `"x" + 5` when you should be doing `"x" + "5"`.  The error message basically told you this.  Just read the error message, look at the code, think about it, and modify your code accordingly.

Comment: As suggested by @PadraicCunningham i found something like 

    `print("the time is about {} o'clock".format(int(y)+1))`

 more elegant (and more performant?) than something like

   `print("some string" + str(some_var) + "some string")`

(especially if their is more than one variable to format), but you will end with the same result.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question after getting an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to concatenate string and integer objects! Convert the object `y` (or `y+1`) to string and then append. Like:

```
print("the time is about quarter past" + str(y)) #similarly str(int(y)+1)
```

Comment: `y` is a string I think so to add 1 you need to `str(int(y) + 1)`

Comment: Correct, I just fixed that in the answer.

Comment: @SuperSaiyan if `y` is a string I guess it should be str(int(y)+1) more than str(int(y+1))

Comment: @mgc: It was a typo, fixed that. Thanks for pointint out.

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast to a string. You are trying to concatenate an int and a string together, which are not compatible.

```
def approxTime(x, y):
     if int(y) <= 24:
         print("the time is about quarter past" + str(y))
     elif 25 >= int(y) <=40:
         print("the time is about half past" + str(y))
     elif 41 >= int(y) <= 54:
         print("the time is about quarter past" + str(y+1))
     else:
         print("the time is about" + str(y+1) +"o'clock")
approxTime(3, 18)
```